# How to make sure the constructor is executed when I'm trying to reach a static property?

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

I have a class for the user details.
I want to call for example UserDetails::$email from my application, but it's empty becuase it does not execute the constructor. How should I solve this?

```
<?php

class UserDetails {

    public static $email;
    private $password;
    public static $role;
    public static $active;

    public function __construct() {
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            $this->email = $auth->getIdentity()->email;
            $this->password = $auth->getIdentity()->password;
            $this->role = $auth->getIdentity()->role;
            $this->active = $auth->getIdentity()->active;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you creating the `new UserDetails` object before trying to access the `::email` method?

Comment: No I'm not. So I can't just reach by UserDetails::$email, everytime I should instantiate it ? Sorry i'm new to OOP.

Comment: Yes, you need to instantiate it before trying to access the properties. If possible, instantiate in a higher level scope so you don't need to do it so often.

Comment: [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/)

Answer (score 3):

I think you should read up on OOP basics. Your class has some major mistakes in it.

First of all, your constructor will not set `$email`, `$role`, or `$active`. You declared those fields as static. Static fields can only be accessed from a static context. The constructor is not a static context.

If you wanted those fields to be static -- and you don't -- you would set them from a static method like this:

```
public static function setEmail($email)
{
    self::$email = $email;
}
```

There is no reason for those fields to be static. Each `$email`, `$role`, and `$active` are tied to a specific user who is tied to a specific *instance* of your UserDetails class.

Finally, those fields should not be public. Public fields can be accessed directly from outside of the class. This means that anyone can change the value of a public field at any time from any script. You should make the fields private or protected and access them through public getter methods.

Here's an example of what a basic stub for this class might look like:

```
<?php

class user {

    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;
    private $email;
    private $password;
    private $role;


    public function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $email, $password, $role)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->role = $role;
    }


    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }


    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }


    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }


}
```

You would use the class like this:

You would use it like this:

```
$don_draper = new user('Donald', 'Draper, 'dondraper@gmail.com', '123xYz', 'admin');

$email = $don_draper->getEmail();
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot initialize a static property to another variable, to a function return value, or to an object.

I thing you should take a look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php